# Как исправить Location Background Service в Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Сервис вызывается в MainActivity.
При сворачивании приложения координаты определяются 1 раз и всё.
Потом через некоторое время сервис убивается.

class MyServiceNew : Service() {

```
    val TAG = "APK: CONSOLE - SERVICE"
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "My Service")
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate")
        super.onCreate()
        fusedLocationClient = FusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        updateLocationTracking()
    }

    private fun updateLocationTracking() {

                val request = LocationRequest().apply {
                    interval = 3000
                    fastestInterval = 1000
                    priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                }

                fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                    request,
                    locationCallback,
                    Looper.getMainLooper()
                )
    }

    private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(result: LocationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(result)
            result.lastLocation
            onLocationChanged(result.lastLocation)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy")
        //stopLocationUpdates()
    }

    private fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged $location")
    }


}
```

**Решение.**
Действительно. Как подсказал в комментариях @Wlad , нужно было перевести сервис с Background в Foreground.
Для этого нужно было создать канал уведомлений и запустить процесс startForeground в методе onStartCommand

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "My Service")
        createNotificationChannel()

        val myIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel1")
            .setContentTitle("My app")
            .setContentText("Our app runnig")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)

        updateLocationTracking()

        return START_STICKY
    }

private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("channel1", "Foreg Notif", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
}
```

Comment: так и должны быть. обычный сервис живет, пока живо приложение. чтобы сервис жил без активити, вам надо сделать Foreground Service.

Comment: А какой практический смыс в бэкграунд сервисе если приложение и его активити активно?

Comment: Foreground появился относительно недавно (2-3 года назад). и его ключевое отличие в том, чтобы у юзера было оповещение вверху (в шторке) в стиле "что-то работает в фоне, даже если вы закроете приложение". я даже не знаю, с какой целью надо применить сейчас обычный Background )) никогда им не пользовался)

Comment: Спасибо друг, вопрос решился. Дописал ответ в исходное сообщение.

Comment: Вот только foreground требует нотификацию, а поэтому можно выделить его в отдельный канал и позволить пользователю его скрыть.